# Why do most DP mechanisms consider constant noise variance across data points?

Tags: privacy, databases, data-leakage

I have been studying Differential Privacy (DP) and there’s something I do not understand: why is the variance of the noise in most DP schemes constant across all individuals (assuming a one-to-one relationship between individuals and data points). Some individuals may be close to the statistic that DP allows to compute to privately and thus may require less noise than outliers in the dataset. As a result, DP is over-protecting those individuals. Wouldn’t it be more efficient (greater utility) to adapt the noise according to the information that each individual data point reveals?